# Версии и различия ассемблера

Tags: ассемблер

Здравствуйте. Я в ассемблере полный профан, но решил все-таки заполнить дыру в знаниях в этой области. Но у меня возник один вопрос:

1. ассемблер - это единый, неизменяющийся язык? То есть, я могу взять любую книгу по ассемблеру, не важно, насколько она стара, и начать учить, и при этом в будущем мне не придется читать более новую книгу по, возможно, новой версии ассемблера? Или все-таки язык ассемблера изменялся?

1. Посоветуйте литературу новичку.

Заранее спасибо

Comment: язык ассемблера привязан к процессору. Каждый процессор имеет свой набор команд. Некоторые процессоры включают в себя команды предыдущих моделей - к примеру, интеловские процессоры можно выстроить в подобную линию (а может не совсем линию).

Но скорее всего напрямую на ассемблере обычно  не пишут - используют синтаксис fasm/masm или gas.

Answer (score 3):

Фактически, ассемблер - это мнемоническая надстройка над машинными командами процессора и базовыми моделями операционных систем.

Например, на Intel-совместимых процессорах свое количество регистров общего назначения, свой набор машинных команд, а также свои модели памяти операционной системы. На IBM mainframe набор регистров (16 регистров общего назначения) и команд совершенно другой и своя организация моделей памяти операционной системы.

Кроме того в рамках одного и того же семейства процессоров могут быть существенные изменения как в наборе команд, так и в моделях памяти, которые поддерживают операционные системы. Например, на ранних моделях Intel-совместимых процессорах были 16-битовые регистры такие, как, например, AX, BX, CX, DX и другие. В настоящее время используются 32-битовые регистры такие, как EAX, EBX, ECX, EDX и другие. Соответственно поддерживаются разные модели памяти, хотя есть некоторое пересечение.

Поэтому если изучать ассемблер, то лучше конечно для современных процессоров.

Сейчас ассемблеры не пользуются популярностью, а потому основные гиганты софтверной индустрии не выпускают отдельных пакеты ассемблеров и соответствующих средств разработки с их использованием. Они уже давно отказались это делать, так как рынок этих продуктов крайне мал.

Ассемблеры могут входить в средства разработки других сред и языков программирования как некоторые низкоуровневые дополнительные утилиты, например, для отладки программ.

Я вам советую заглянуть на сайт Intel, и там посмотреть, какие есть ссылки относительно ассемблера для Intel-совместимых процессоров. Также можно покопаться с поиском в интернет в надежде обнаружить поддерживаемые ассемблеры и средства работы с ними группами энтузиастов. Может также поискать на сайте Microsoft информацию относительно их ассемблера и соответствующей документации.

Comment: AX, BX, CX и т.д. - 16-битные регистры, EAX, EBX и т.д. - 32-битные, RAX, RBX - 64-битные.

Comment: @insolor Да, вы правы. Поправлю свой ответ.